# Homeomorphism between $S^1\times \Bbb{R}$ and $\Bbb{R}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$

Tags: general-topology

> I need to show that there exists a homeomorphism between $S^1\times \Bbb{R}$ and $\Bbb{R}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$

If we map $(\cos x, \sin x,y) \to (y\cos x,y\sin x)$ then only problem is that it is taking value $(0,0)$. Can we modify this or will any other map work?

Comment: Find a homeomorphism $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R^+$.

Comment: okay $e^x$ will work,then?

Comment: Is This map works :$(\cos x, \sin x,y) \to (e^y\cos x,e^y\sin x)$